# Using accumarray for a weighted average?

Tags: matlab, accumarray

`accumarray` in Matlab is amazing, and I use it often.  I have a problem where the function I would like to pass to `accumarray` is a weighted average.  i.e. it takes in two vectors, not a single vector.  This appears to be a use case not supported by `accumarray`.

Is my understanding correct?

Consider, the function `weightedAverage`

```
function [ result ] = weightedMean( values, weights)

result = sum(values(:).*weights(:)) / sum(weights(:));

end
```

Now, we want to run `accumarray` as follows:

```
subs    = [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3];
vals    = [1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7];
weights = [3 2 1 9 1 9 9 9];

accumarray(subs, [vals;weights],[], @weightedMean)
```

but matlab returns:

```
Error using accumarray
Second input VAL must be a vector with one element for each row in SUBS, or a scalar.
```

Comment: I don't know. Can you give us an example? Maybe the code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the second input must be *either* a column vector or a scalar. Rather than passing your *data* to `accumarray`, you can pass an array of indices which you can then use to index into your `values` and `weights` vectors from within the anonymous function which computes your weighted average.

```
inds = [1 1 2 2 3 3].';
values =  [1 2 3 4 5 6];
weights = [1 2 1 2 1 2];

output = accumarray(inds(:), (1:numel(inds)).', [], ...
                    @(x)sum(values(x) .* weights(x) ./ sum(weights(x))))
%    1.6667
%    3.6667
%    5.6667
```